# Unable to list EC2 instances from inside lambda function Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have been trying to run a lambda function to retrieve the details of EC2 instances in my region.

Here is my code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-1'});


exports.handler = async function(event) {

  var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

  var params = {
    DryRun: false
  };
  let results = ec2.describeInstances(params, (data, err) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }else{
      console.log(data)
    }
  }) ;

  return "Done"
```

}

There seems to be no console.log print from inside ec2.describeInstances at all. I have made sure that the EC2 instances I need is in the same VPC as lambda and that the lambda has EC2FullAccess permissions.

Comment: Use `const results = await ec2.describeInstances(params).promise()`

Comment: Thanks for this. It turns out that, the async function was returning a promise without fully running ec2.describeInstances(params). Your code did the trick. I had to increase the timeout however.